# Can a single 'when' clause handle multiple exception types in oracle?

Tags: oracle, exception

Suppose I have a procedure as follows:

```
PROCEDURE proc_name (args)
IS

  --  declarations
    ...
BEGIN

    -- code
    ...
EXCEPTION

    WHEN an_error THEN

        --error handling code
         ....
        WHEN another_error THEN

        -- error handling code, identical to the one for an_error
         ...
     WHEN others THEN
       ---generic error handling code`
       ....
END;
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to catch both `an_error` and `another_error` in the same WHEN clause, since their handling is identical.

Is this possible in Oracle? If not, what are other possibilities to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can use OR conditions between the exceptions so

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN an_exception 
    OR another_exception
  THEN
    handle it here;
END;
```

See [The Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exception_handler.htm#LNPLS01316) for more details on exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But not for OTHERS exception. It can not be merged with another exception.